# Appending functions to list

Tags: output-formatting

Help me please.

My task is to determine the sequence of polynomials $(s,s',..,-rem(fs_{k-1},s_{k}),...,constant)$ and create an array in which I will record the value of the members of this sequence at two points $({{s[a],s[b]},{s'[a],s'[b]},...}$ .

I define polynomial $s[x]$ and then I want to calculate derivative $s[x]$ as function, but I have no idea, how I can do this:

```
s[x_]:=x^4-5*x^2-2*x+5
s1[x_]:=D[s[x],x]
```

it is wrong, because in this way I will differentiate by constant. And if I will have $s[x]$ and $s1[x]$, I can recursively determine the sequence:

```
a[x_]:= s[x]
b[x_]:= s1[x]
h[x_]:= -PolynomialRemainder[s[x], s1[x], x];
```

I have a similar problem in this step, because $h[x]$ isn't function.

Next, I want to recursively determine the sequence and record the value of polynomials at two points at each step (until the function becomes constant).

```
values = {};
a1 = 0;
a2 = 1;
While[\[Not] TrueQ[D[h[x], x] == 0],a[x_]:= b[x];  b[x_]:=h[x]; 
h[x] = -PolynomialRemainder[a[x], b[x], x]; AppendTo[values, {h[a1],h[a2]}];]]
```

but expectedly the program is working incorrectly.

I will be grateful for any help.

UPD1:

```
s[x_] := x^3 - 5*x^2 - 2 x + 2;
ClearAll[s1]; s1[x_] := s'[x];
```

Comment: define `s1` as `ClearAll[s1]; s1[x_] := D[s[t], t] /. t -> x`?

Comment: @kglr Thank you!

Comment: ... or use `ClearAll[s1]; s1[x_] := s'[x]`

Comment: I'm confused about your desired sequence - what are a and b in the second round? Is it `a=h` and `b=h'`? Or `a=s' and b=h`, as seems to be indicated in your While loop?

Answer (score 1):

A possible approach is to use [`NestWhileList`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NestWhileList.html) as follows:

```
ClearAll[s, prem, nwl]
s[x_] := x^4-5*x^2-2*x+5
prem[a_, b_, x_] := -PolynomialRemainder[a, b, x] 
nwl[f_, maxsteps_] := Most @ 
   NestWhileList[{#[[3]], D[#[[3]], x], prem[#[[1]], #[[2]], x]} &, 
    {f[x], f'[x], prem[f[x], f'[x], x]},  
    Not[PossibleZeroQ[#[[2]]]] &, 1, maxsteps]

nwl[s, 10]
```

> {{5 - 2 x - 5 x^2 + x^4, -2 - 10 x + 4 x^3, -5 + (3 x)/2 + (5 x^2)/
>          2}, {-5 + (3 x)/2 + (5 x^2)/2, 
>         3/2 + 5 x, -5 + (3 x)/2 + (5 x^2)/2}, {-5 + (3 x)/2 + (5 x^2)/2, 
>         3/2 + 5 x, 209/40}}

```
Flatten @ nwl[s, 10]
```

> {5 - 2 x - 5 x^2 + x^4, -2 - 10 x + 4 x^3, -5 + (3 x)/2 + (5 x^2)/
>         2, -5 + (3 x)/2 + (5 x^2)/2, 
>        3/2 + 5 x, -5 + (3 x)/2 + (5 x^2)/2, -5 + (3 x)/2 + (5 x^2)/2, 
>        3/2 + 5 x, 209/40}

Evaluating each entry at `a1` and `a2` and reorganizing the resulting list:

```
a1 = 0; a2 = 1;
Riffle @@ (Flatten@nwl[s, 10] /. {{x -> a1}, {x -> a2}})
```

> {5, -1, -2, -8, -5, -1, -5, -1, 3/2, 13/2, -5, -1, -5, -1, 3/2, 13/2, 209/40, 209/40}

Answer (score 1):

Your approach basically makes sense.

```
s[x_] := x^4 - 5*x^2 - 2*x + 5
s1[f_] := D[f, x] 
h[f1_, f2_, x_] := -PolynomialRemainder[f1, f2, x]

values = {};
a1 = 0;
a2 = 1;
a = s[x];
b = s1[s[x]];
done = False;

While[! done,
 pr = h[a, b, x];
 AppendTo[values, {a, b, pr} /. x -> {a1, a2}];
 a = pr;
 b = s1[a];
 If[D[pr, x] == 0, done = True];
]

values
```

> {{{5, -1}, {-2, -8}, {-5, -1}}, {{-5, -1}, {3/2, 13/2}, 209/40}}

I'm not sure I understood the definition of the sequence - if it's not right, it should be easy to fix by changing the assignments of `a` and `b` inside the While loop.